# Can we define function after main without prototype declaration?

Tags: c++, function

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum(int ,int);
int sum(int ,int );
int main(){
    cout<<sum(1,3)<<endl;
}
int sum(int a,int b){
    cout<<"hi "<<endl;
    return a+b;
}
int sum(int a,int b,char c){
    return a+b+c;
}
```

In the above program, I have defined a function after main without prototype declaration but the compiler did not generate error  message.

Comment: You definitely can! t

Comment: You can define functions in any order you want. The only requirement is that you have a declaration (or full definition) before you *call* it

Comment: Why do you think you can't?

Answer (score 5):

Prototypes are not strictly necessary.  Functions must be *declared* before they are used, and *defined* (somewhere) if they are used.

Separate declarations allows header files to announce the existence of a function, while another file actually defines it (.c, .cpp, or even a  library).

However, if you simply implement a function without a prototype, then the definition is *also* its own declaration.  If it shares the same name as another existing function with a different signature, it simply adds to the overload set (from that point onward) for that name.

Finally, it is not an error to define a function that isn't called.  Think about how many functions are declared when you include `<iostream>` that you haven't called!  Unused functions will not appear in the final resulting artifact being produced.

Problems that can arise occur when you provide multiple definitions for the *same* function (linker error), or different translation units provide different definitions of inline functions (One Definition Rule (ODR) violation).

Comment: What do you mean with "prototypes are not strictly necessary"?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica s/strictly/always ? I took "strictly" to mean "always", as it can do.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica By that, I meant you can define a function even if it's not previously declared.  Headers with inline functions do this all the time.  I.e. it is _not_ required to `void f(); void f() { }`, with the first being an explicit prototype, and the second being a definition.  You can simply `void f() { }` and it is its own declaration.  If other files want to call it and the function definition isn't immediately visible, then a prototype will be enough info to satisfy the compiler, and the linker will find/resolve the function's symbol later.